# LaTeX/Packages/Listings and subindex

Tags: packages, listings, code

I am using [LaTeX/Packages/Listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) AND this code to make a rectangle with sql source code inside of it, but I would like to have the option to insert subindexes...

I try it using the following but had no success, any idea?

```
\lstset{language=SQL, caption=SQL, label=SQL, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{blue}}
\begin{lstlisting}
       SELECT  SUM($x_{1}$ *$x_{1}$ FROM X;
\end{lstlisting}
```

I would like to make the `$x_1$` shows right

Comment: I think you need to add `mathescape=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `mathescape=true`. Here is the output without and with this added:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=SQL, caption=SQL, label=SQL, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{blue}}
\begin{lstlisting}
       SELECT  SUM($x_{1}$ *$x_{1}$ FROM X;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
       SELECT  SUM($x_{1}$ *$x_{1}$ FROM X;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more question, Is it possible to change the title `"Listing 1", "Listing 2".... "Listing n"?` to a different title?

Comment: @cMinor `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}` will change `Listing n` to `Code n`.